# jQuery - What is the difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I was examining one of my client's code and came across this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function foo1() {
        $("#id1").bind('click', function() {});
    }
    foo1();

    function foo2() {
        $("#id2").bind('click', function() {});
    }
    foo2();
});
```

What they are doing is, attaching event handler inside the function and then calling that function.

How does it differ from the following?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id1").bind('click', function() {});
    $("#id2").bind('click', function() {});
});
```

That is attaching event handlers directly in `$(document).ready()` function.

It works fine in both the scenarios, I was just wondering if there are some performance related issues or something. Like one works faster or slower. Or is it a standard way of doing things which I am not aware of.

Comment: If you use JQuery >1.7, you will want to use `.on` instead of `.bind`. For your question, it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference it you can re-use that part of your code to call foo2() at any place in your code again instead of copy the whole code.

EDIT:

**Let me give you an example**

On failure it needs to show an alert with 'Hello, that was going wrong!' you can do these two things:

```
alert('Hello, that was going wrong!');
```

or

```
function showError() {
alert('Hello, that was going wrong!');
} 
showError();
```

Solution 1 seems to be the easiest one.

*But.....* Imagine you are  working on a really large project with places to show that error on 1000 places. Now you need to edit your message at 1000 places instead of just one place.

Or when you want to show an HTML popup instead of an alert, imagine changing that.

Hopes the explanation it makes sense, when not please let me know.

Comment: hehe.. yes :)
I understand what you are saying. I was asking if there is some performance related issue. Creatind functions lets you reuse the code.

Comment: There won't be a lot of performance difference, not on this small type of differences. :)